# Intentar capturar hora de base de datos

Tags: c#

Al intentar mostrar la hora que tiene un campo de mi base de datos 
en un DateTimePiker

me aparece la siguiente excepción :

**System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.TimeSpan' to type 'System.IConvertible'.'**

Codigo

```
   private void BtnEditarForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
            {
                FormAddActividad frm = new FormAddActividad
                {
                    operacion = "Editar"
                };
                frm.ListarActividad1();
                frm.ListarComplet();
                frm.ListarTipo();
                frm.ListarPrioridad();
                frm.ListarEstado();
                frm.ListarResponsable();
                frm.CodActi = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                frm.txtReferencia.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                frm.txtActividad.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                frm.cmbTarea.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                frm.cmbTipo.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
                frm.cmbPrioridad.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
                frm.cmbEstado.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value.ToString();
                frm.cmbResponsable.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[7].Value.ToString();
                frm.dateCreacion.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["FCreacion"].Value);
                frm.dateInicio.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["FInicio"].Value);
                frm.dateFin.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["FFin"].Value);
                frm.dateHHInicio.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["HInicio"].Value);
                frm.dateHFin.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["Hin"].Value);
                frm.cmbCompletado.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["NomComplet"].Value.ToString();
                frm.txtNotas.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["Notas"].Value.ToString();
                frm.ShowDialog();
                ListarActividad();
            }
            else MessageBox.Show("Debe seleccionar una fila ");
        }
```

**img**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: que dato asignas a esa celda ? porque si es un ahora deberias ser con alguna formato como ser hh:mm:ss o algo asi si te reconoce el dato como TimeSpan quiere decir que no esta en formato correcto que pueda castear a datetime

Comment: Queres tomar la hora del sistema? Probaste usar string Hora = DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmmss");? En este caso, el campo de tu base de datos no debería ser time sino string.

Comment: Necesitaba obtener la hora insertada en un campo de la base de datos